# how do I pass image data to a native module in React Native?

Tags: react-native, uiimage, nsdata, native-methods, native-module

In my class that implements the `RCTBridgeModule` protocol in Xcode, I am trying to write an `RCT_EXPORT_MEATHOD` that I can expose to React Native code to consume image data. Currently, I can write an image to disk in React Native, and then pass the path through to the native method, but I'm wondering if there is a better technique to pass image data directly for better performance?

**So instead of this:**

```
RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(scanImage:(NSString *)path) {
  UIImage *sampleImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];  
  [self processImage: UIImage];
}
```

**Something more like this:**

```
RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(scanImage:(NSData *)imageData) {
  [self processImageWithData: imageData];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `[RCTConvert UIImage:icon]` method from `#import <React/RCTConvert.h>`

You need to specify "schema" as "data".
For more details look at the source code bellow:
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/React/Base/RCTConvert.m#L762

Comment: Could you add a code example how to specify this schema as data? Also there is a comment in that section saying:  "This method is only used when loading images synchronously, e.g. for tabbar icons".. Are you sure about using it like this?

Answer (score 0):

For me, this works:

```
  NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[imagePath stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet]]];
  UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]];
```

`imagePath` is `NSString` comes from the react-native bridge (using `react-native-image-picker`'s response - `response.uri`).